# Create high level parallax scroll effect

Tags: animation, svg, web-applications, parallax, web-testing

Hi I want to create a website with scroll animations like

1. https://www.tagheuer.com/fr/en/smartwatches/collection-connected.html
2. https://delassus.com/en/

but ***don't know where to start or how to do it***. I believe that I would have to create IMAGE SEQUENCES (videos) and animate it on scroll with SVG backgrounds but need advice. Please share your thoughts.

Appreciations for your time,
Thanks.

Comment: ILL BE UPLOADING SOME TECHNIQUES THAT WORK IN THIS REGARDS AS I MAKE PROGRESS

Comment: I have you got any solution for this effects? any plugins please share